# Get signature of @staticmethod before metaclass instance is created

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

I want to call `inspect.signature` within the `__new__` of a python metaclass, before calling `super().__new__`. This seems to be working fine with non-static methods but raises errors on static methods. Is this intended behaviour? Is there a way to work around it?

For example, this code:

```
import inspect

class M(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        result = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
        print(name, 'dot', repr(inspect.signature(result.x)))
        print(name, 'get', repr(inspect.signature(namespace['x'])))
        return result

class C1(metaclass=M):
    def x(self, a: int):
        pass

class C2(metaclass=M):
    @staticmethod
    def x(self, a: int):
        pass
```

Produces this error:

```
C1 dot <Signature (self, a: int)>
C1 get <Signature (self, a: int)>
C2 dot <Signature (self, a: int)>
TypeError: <staticmethod object at 0x0000014ED0693940> is not a callable object
```

When attempting to get the signature of the static method before calling `__new__`, there is a type error.

Comment: They talked about making staticmethods callable recently on the mailing list, but I don't think they got around to doing it. I think it's just an awkward inconsistency and they should fix it.

Comment: @Hatshepsut the point is that making staticmethods callable adds one useless function call, so it's a question of balance between uniformity and performances. Since for most use cases this "awkward inconsistency" is a complete non-issue (how often has this been a serious issue for you actually ? As far as I'm concerned, the answer is "not even once in 20 years" - but YMMV of course).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I agree there's a balance. FWIW, I've seen this issue arise before. Staticmethods aren't especially common anyway, so the performance impact  would be quite limited in scope. As we know, "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules." :-)

Comment: I'm not saying one choice is "better" than the other - I just thought I'd mention the reasons behind this choice, whether you (generic "you") agree with this decision is another question ;-)

Comment: Here's the relevant issue filed by CPython 3.5 release manager Larry Hastings https://bugs.python.org/issue20309 and [draft PEP 579](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0579/#static-methods-and-class-methods-should-be-callable).

Comment: Oh and yes: `staticmethods` are of limited use in Python indeed, but having to do "meta stuff" (inspecting, bypassing the attribute resolution etc) on staticmethods is even rarer - and most often when you're in this situation you are expected to know how to deal with some low-level details (or else to learn about them xD), so as far as I'm concerned I think that optimizing the most common use case makes perfect sense (=> "Although practicality beats purity")

Answer (score 3):

> This seems to work fine on non-static methods, but raises errors on static methods. Is this intended behavior?

The fact that staticmethods are not callable is indeed intended - [the `staticmethod` object is a descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) whose `__get__` method just returns the function it decorates.

As to why it works this way, [this is because of how "methods" are implemented](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod) in Python, [which forces functions intended to be staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods) to be wrapped [to prevent the function's own descriptors protocol to be invoked at lookup time](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods). It would of course have been possible to make `staticmethod` objects callable (just like methods and classmethods), but this would have implied a supplementary, technically useless, function call (and function calls don't come for free...).

> Is there a way to work around it?

There are a couple indeed. You can force the invocation of the protocol descriptor either implicitely by triggering attribute resolution - which is actually what you're doing with `result.x` - or manually using :

```
x = namespace["x"]
x = x.__get__(result)
```

Or you can (as answered by Craig Gidney) do some typechecking and directly retrieve the `.__func__` attribute of the staticmethod.

I'd personnaly advise to stick to the first solution if possible as it's the one that's the most generic and doesn't break encapsulation. Note that if your issue to find out which names are defined in the class, you can still use the `namespace` dict's keys together with `getattr`:

```
for name in namespace:
    val = getattr(result, name)
    if callable(val):
        print("{} is a callable".format(val))
```

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to manually check for and unwrap `staticmethod`, like this:

```
    x = namespace['x']
    if isinstance(x, staticmethod):
        x = x.__func__
    print(inspect.signature(x))
```